# Trying to format text from api data in an HTML element

Tags: javascript, html, api

Calling data from a weather api site.  Have console logged the data to make sure it is in fact showing up.  But cant seem to replace elements in HTML with the data from the api.

I am confused on what functions I need to use to replace the placeholder text with the data from the api.  I have tried innerHTML, textContent, and innerText.  I either get undefined with innerHTML or nothing at all with textContent.

```
const api = `https://api.weather.io/v1.0/current?city=NewYork,NY&key=`;

let temperature = document.getElementById('temp');

fetch (api)
  .then(response => {
    return response.json();
  })
  .then(data => {
    console.log(data);
    temperature.innerHTML = data.temp ;
  });
```

the api data is logged like so:

data:
0:
rh  57
pod "d"
lon -78.63861
pres    1007.3
timezone    "America/New_York"
ob_time "2019-10-28 17:40"
country_code    "US"
clouds  0

I expect the variable (temperature) to equal the string value of the api data.

Comment: The variable temperature can not be equal to string value of the api data. temperature is holding a reference to DOM element. With help of this you are trying to attach content. I think the problem is data does not have a property called temp. In the output of your console log for data there is no key as "temp"

Comment: Yeah, it comes down to the data type and what properties you have access to.  temerature.innerHTML is just fine (assuming 'temperature' is a valid reference to an element).  If you set temperature.innerHTML = "STUFF" you should see 'STUFF' show up on the screen showing that the mechanism for getting data to the screen is OK.  It comes down to knowing what properties 'data' has access to.

Comment: I think the problem is how I am trying to access the information in data.  When I console log all the data it appears like so.  data:  0:  temp: 65.  Would I have to include the 0? example temperature.innerHTML = data.0.temp; ?

Comment: Is there any way for you to include the HTML output as part of the question? It's hard to know what elements we can offer to help you modfiy if we have no idea how it's being generated